# Не могу изменить Content Options главной страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Не могу изменить Content Options главной страницы wordpress, нужно отредактировать вывод текста в шорткодах
[image: Скриншот]

вносимые изменения не сохраняются

Comment: посмотри https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9 и ссылки в нём

Comment: У меня другая проблема. Страницы, записи все создается. не могу изменить содержимое content options

Comment: А что это за счастье такое - "Content Options". В стандартном WP такого нет. Если вы используете плагины или нестандартные темы, их надо указывать в вопросе.

Comment: Тогда вопрос к тому, кто создавал это  content options.